# How to include an image with white background in a page with a background image on LATEX

Tags: graphics

I have a front page with a background image and I want to include a logo that has white background, how to do that without appearing the white background of the logo? I tried includegraphics but it didn't work

Comment: What is the format of the logo image (PDF, EPS, PNG, ...)?

Comment: it's a JPEG file, do I need any specific image extension?

Comment: Then you can use the first method of my answer using GIMP, for example.

Comment: JPEG is both a bitmap and it is not a lossless format. Usually logos are created as vector graphics. The the quality is the best and maybe this version does not even have a white background. Maybe, you can try and get such a version. The conversion to bitmap is often done for web pages, where size matters and the resolution does not need to be high. But, such a bitmap is usually not suited for printing.

Answer (score 1):

The best way heavily depends on the format of the logo image. Examples:

- RGB or grayscale bitmap can be opened in [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org/):

  1. If the image mode is not RGB, then convert it to RGB: Image -> Mode -> RGB
  2. Then convert white to transparent (alpha channel): Colors -> Color to Alpha.
- Vector image as EPS or PDF: PDF can be uncompressed by [PDFtk](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/), e.g.:

  ```text
  pdftk input.pdf cat output output.pdf uncompress
  ```

  Then, the operation for the white background can be tried to be identified
  and removed. It requires some knowledge of the format.
  If it is just a white background that is drawn at the beginning,
  then it might be not to difficult. Both EPS and PDF have `%` as comment
  character until the end of line. However, the PDF file should be overwritten
  only, no characters should be inserted or deleted. Otherwise the positions for
  the cross-reference table gets invalidated.

  It can be much more problematic, if the white color is used to overwrite other
  colored parts.