# Metropolis theme [beamer], changing the background of logo in the title page

Tags: beamer, backgrounds, frame-title, logos, beamer-metropolis

I'm using the metropolis theme for beamer presentation and i have some problems with logo. In fact, I want to change the white background of my eps logo to the transparent one, so that only the colors of the letters are visible (red, blue, gray and not white).

The eps file is [here](http://liris.cnrs.fr/dgtal/cgi-bin/trac.cgi/browser/branches/0.3.1/doc/PosterDGCI/Images/liris-logo.eps?rev=1211)  and i donwload the png version to see what the figure looks like.

[image]

Thanks

Below you find my MWE  and the screen of my document:

```
   \documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
   \usetheme[subsectionpage=progressbar,background=light]{metropolis}
   \usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer}
   \usepackage{booktabs}
   \usepackage[scale=2]{ccicons}
   \usepackage{xspace}
   \newcommand{\themename}{\textbf{\textsc{metropolis}}\xspace}



   \titlegraphic{%
      \includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth]{example-image-a}\hfill
      \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=1.6cm]{logo.eps}\hfill
      \includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth]{example-image-b}

   }

   \makeatletter
   \setbeamertemplate{title page}{
     \begin{minipage}[b][\paperheight]{\textwidth}

       \vfill%
       \ifx\inserttitlegraphic\@empty\else\inserttitlegraphic\fi
        \centering
        \vfill%
       \ifx\inserttitle\@empty\else\usebeamertemplate*{title}\fi
       \ifx\insertsubtitle\@empty\else\usebeamertemplate*{subtitle}\fi
       \usebeamertemplate*{title separator}
       \ifx\beamer@shortauthor\@empty\else\usebeamertemplate*{author}\fi
       \ifx\insertinstitute\@empty\else\usebeamertemplate*{institute}\fi
       \ifx\insertdate\@empty\else\usebeamertemplate*{date}\fi
       \vfill
        \vspace*{1cm}
     \end{minipage}
   }

   \setbeamertemplate{title}{
   %  \raggedright%
     \linespread{1.0}%
     \inserttitle%
     \par%
     \vspace*{0.15em}
   }
   \setbeamertemplate{subtitle}{
   %  \raggedright%
      \insertsubtitle%
      \par%
      \vspace*{0.5em}
   }
   \makeatother


   \title{My long long long long long long long long long long Title  }
   \subtitle{My subtitle}
   \author{FirstName LastName \\ Supervisor: My supervisor}
   \institute{My Institute}
   \date{\today}


   \begin{document}
   \begin{frame}
       \titlepage
   \end{frame}
   \end{document}
```

[image]

Secondly I would like to know how to create a command for a supervisor information (like \author, \institute, \date, ...) instead of putting his name in the author command ? and how to place it just under the author name ?

Comment: For the second, although I don't know if it could be applied to `beamer`, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58506/how-to-make-a-new-command-similar-to-author

Comment: For the first: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/384186/how-to-include-an-image-with-white-background-in-a-page-with-a-background-image/384191#384191

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The .eps file you linked to is no true vector graphic but simply has an image included. Thus the quality will not get any worse if you simply remove the white background from the logo, e.g. with gimp. The resulting image:

[image]

This logo can be included as usual (I added `keepaspectratio` to not distort the image):

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme[subsectionpage=progressbar,background=light]{metropolis}

\titlegraphic{%
  \includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth]{example-image-a}\hfill
  \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=1.6cm,keepaspectratio]{mJeal}\hfill
  \includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth]{example-image-b}

}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
   \titlepage
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but i dont know how I do remove the wihte background and get an eps file instead of png picture  ?

Comment: @FiesAtoS Why do you want an eps file? For non-vector images you can just as well use the png file. You don't need to remove the background, I already did this for you: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJeal.png

Comment: Yes but when I compile with png file i get this error : Cannot determine size of graphic in mJeal.png .   I use fast compile and i can't use pdfLatex . Thanks again

Comment: @FiesAtoS I am not sure if .eps supports transparency.